# Estimating Markov Chains

Tags: probability

Long time viewer, first time posting here!

In an introductory course in Statistics and Probability, we are often presented with basic examples on Discrete Time Markov Chains. We are usually given a transition matrix with transition probabilities corresponding to some Discrete Time Markov Chain and are asked to find out some properties. For example, we might be asked to determine if this Markov Chain is Ergodic, or is this Markov Chain has a Limiting Distribution or if this Markov Chain has a Stationary Distribution.

I have always wondered about how these transition probabilities are estimated in real life problems. My guess is that for a Discrete Time Markov Chain, we don't really need any fancy/complicated estimation algorithms - rather, we can do this directly from the data. For example, suppose we have the "state" of the financial market for 365 days (i.e. data available exactly once a day) - let's assume the market can either be in one of two states: "BEAR" or "BULL". This means that the data would look something like this : Jan-1 = BEAR, JAN-2 = BEAR, JAN-3 = BULL ... , DEC-29 = BEAR, DEC-30 = BULL, DEC-31 = BULL. In my opinion, to estimate the transition probabilities for BEAR-BULL, you would count the number of times BEAR is followed by BULL and divide this by the total number of times BULL appears (e.g. number_of_times_BEAR_followed_by_BULL /  number_of_times_BEAR_followed_by_BULL +  number_of_times_BEAR_followed_by_BEAR). You could then repeat this process for BEAR-BEAR, BULL-BULL, BULL-BEAR. These will serve as the estimates for the discrete transition probabilities at the daily level.

However, I have heard that estimating transition probabilities in a Continuous Time Markov Chain is not so simple and often involves some algorithm such as Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE), Expectation-Maximization Algorithm (EM), Baum-Welch Algorithm or the Viterbi Algorithm - but I am not sure about these details. I tried to read more about this but so far I am having difficulty understanding this topic. In a Continuous Markov Chain, transitions can happen at irregular times (compared to the fixed times as in the discrete case). In a Homogenous Continuous Time Markov Chain, the (matrix of) transition probabilities from state-to-state are said to be constant over time - but in addition to just these transition probabilities, we also estimate a "transition rate matrix" that contains the instantaneous rates of transitioning from some current state to another state (dependent on the amount of time you have spent in the current state). This "transition rate matrix" is closely related to the "transition probability matrix".

Here is where my confusion kicks in: Suppose you have a dataset that contains information on the amount of time you spent in some state before transitioning to another state. For example:

```
 index initial_state next_state time_spent_in_initial_state_prior_to_transition
  1             1          2                                        55.48092
  2             2          1                                        32.08635
  3             1          3                                        51.87182
  4             3          2                                       142.95548
  5             2          3                                       108.87524
  6             3          2                                       133.05697
  7             2          1                                       124.60567
  8             1          3                                        39.15136
  9             3          2                                        36.85165
 10             2          3                                       100.48277
 11             3          1                                        35.27872
```

If we wanted to model this data using a Continuous Time (Homogenous) Markov Chain, how would we estimate the transition probabilities?

This link here ([https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/462/lectures/06/markov-mle.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/462/lectures/06/markov-mle.pdf)) explains that transition probabilities of a Discrete Markov Chain can be estimated using Maximum Likelihood (with some logical constraints), but it seems like even with Maximum Likelihood, the formulas for the parameter estimates (i.e. transition probabilities) is still related to the proportion of counts from some state to another state compared to all possible transitions - I am guessing that MLE guarantees that these transition probabilities carry the general properties of MLE estimates such as Unbiasedness, Consistency, Efficiency (Asymptotic).

But how exactly do we use Maximum Likelihood Estimation to estimate the parameters of a Continuous Time Markov Chain - does anyone have any ideas how this is done?

I would be curious to know what people on this forum have to say!

Thank you!

Comment: Like you said, because of the difficulties in estimating CTMC, there are many methods as well - here is a good paper (and software in R) which would estimate them: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-038/RJ-2017-038.pdf

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on how these estimations are done?